# Laravel 9 session expire

Tags: laravel

Using Laravel 9 with Breeze(Auth Scaffolding) to make an admin panel. Throughout my views, I have a

```
auth()->user()->name
```

call that returns the name of the logged in user and works as it should.

Problem is - If I leave the page sitting for a while and the session expires, it doesn't route me to login, it gives me the following error:

Attempt to read property "username" on null

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEwYY.png)

Am I missing something? My routes are all wrapped in middleware => auth group.

After this happens, I manually type logout in the url which logs me out and return a login BUT I always have to login twice. The first login does nothing, no error, no message.

Comment: Show your login controller

Comment: using Laravel Breeze. There is no login controller. There is an AuthenticatedSessionController - would that help ?